# double pointer memory check, do we need to delete both separatly

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

Is it ok to do like this.

```
LPWSTR lpwStr = new LPWSTR;
*lpwStr = new LPWSTR;

if (lpwStr){
    if (*lpwStr)
        delete (*lpwStr);
}
```

Do we need to delete lpwStr also ??? like:

```
if (lpwStr){
    if (*lpwStr) {
        delete (*lpwStr);
    }
    delete lpwStr;
}
```

Second pointer is showing memory leak. which one is correct first one or second one.
Thanks.

Comment: Yes you have to delete both.

Comment: No, it's not ok. The compiler could have told you that.

Comment: This is a bad question, as the sample provides non-working code.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the general rule is that you need a `delete` for every `new` (and a `delete []` for every `new []`).

Note that you don't need the inner check though; it's valid to invoke `delete` on a null pointer.

Answer (score 1):

You have to `delete` **everything** you `new`ed, but I don't understand why or how would you do `*lpwStr = new LPWSTR;`...

Comment: I don't even understand why or how anyone would do `LPWSTR lpwStr = new LPWSTR;`

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes Yeah, most of this code is downright nonsense as-is...

Answer (score 1):

You should `delete` any pointer which `new` by you.

But, I think you are missing something, it should be like this:

```
LPWSTR lpwStr = new WSTR; //<----- WSTR instead of LPWSTR

if (lpwStr)
   delete lpwStr;
```

`LPWSTR` is a type of a pointer to a `WSTR` so you need allocate for `WSTR` by `new WSTR`.

Comment: `delete lpwStr;` can be called directly being `NULL` tolerant.